# Can 20,000 schemas exist in a single Postgres database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, multi-tenant

Can a single Postgres database contain more than 20,000 schemas? What are the implications of such a database design.

I was reading about postgres schemas here - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-schemas.html and I'm planning to create one schema per account in my multi-tenant Ruby on Rails app. Each schema would have a set of tables to store data of the relevant account.

Each user/schema for all the features we offer, could have 50-60 tables.

Can postgres handle all of this without any hiccups, provided I allocate a large EC2 instance to host the database server ?

[update]

By experience if any one faced trouble with such number of schemas in postgres, they could share and i thought i can get more guidance to avoid such pitfalls.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* create 20,000 schemas in a single PostgreSQL database, but that's not to say it's a good idea.

Firstly, from a design point of view if you want to add a new column to a table, that's 20,000 tables to update. Also - if you want to view totals for all users, that's a 20,000 table union you're going to have to write - not pretty.

Secondly, there certainly have historically been some issues with very large numbers of schemas and tables. Not from the point of view of individual queries so much but from anything querying the system catalogues. Certain of the system views and functions have had a simplistic implementation which works fine for 100 tables but is painfully slow for 10,000. That's not always a bad thing - why complicate core functionality for 99% of your users when what you've got works?

There have been some minor tweaks made here and there in the system catalogues to push up the limits for people attempting your sort of design. Where the limits are will depend upon your usage pattern though. It's been a while since I looked at ActiveRecord or any of its kin, but in development mode it used to query the catalogues all the time to check table definitions - that could be painful. In production though, you might not have a problem after a slow startup.

I don't see that the EC2 stuff matters here - so long as you have the CPU and RAM for your requirements.

So - in summary:

- It can be done
- Odd corners will show O(n<sup>2</sup>) rather than O(n log n) performance which with 20,000 schemas will be noticable.

Check the postgresql.org mailing list archives for previous discussion of this - that's the place to go if you really want detailed information.

Comment: Yep. I'd summarize this to "it won't crash, but performance and management will be horrible, so don't do it."

Comment: thanks Richard. The reason why we want to go schema way is for data isolation and easy restore and back up for our customer data. Specific tables for a customer could go very high. We could go multi-database approach but the complexity of maintaining 20,000 database is very high compared to handling 20,000 schemas inside One Database. right? would love to have your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked three questions here, but the bottom line question appears to be *Can postgres handle [20,000 schemas] without any hiccups, provided I allocate a large EC2 instance to host the database server?*

There are are lot more variables involved that go into answering that question, including exactly how big the instance is, the performance level of the EBS storage behind it that you've selected, RAID options, file system selection, how much data is each schema, how much traffic the servers are getting, and what kind of traffic it is.

There is no substitute for running capacity tests for your particular design to see if it will actually work. I think the answers you will get for asking specific questions that come out of that will be much more valuable than any other advice that could be provided with the minimal information currently provided.

For the initial question about whether 20,000 schemas can exist-- create a simple loop and test the idea for yourself and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks. I will do the test by myself. But by experience if any one faced trouble with such number of schemas in postgres, they could share and i thought i can get more guidance to avoid such pitfalls.